# If someone says, "Shoot, it was a great day to be alive." , what does he/she mean?

Tags: meaning

A example sentence from [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shoot):

> Shoot - exclamation
>   North American informal
>   used as a euphemism for ‘shit’:
>
> **shoot, it was a great day to be alive**

What is the tone of this sentence? How to paraphrase it?

Answer (score 1):

Without hearing the intonation my guess would be a tone of happiness

I would guess the speaker to be Texan.

In other parts it could be

> Damn, it was a good day to be alive

or

> Fer Shizzle, it was a good day to be alive -

Answer (score -1):

Shoot is used as an exclamation or a very mild curse, such as "Darn": Oh, shoot! I left phone in the car!